# How to install Sharepoint Foundation for development purposes

Tags: sharepoint

SharepointFoundation 2010 doesnt install on windows 7.

What do I need to have it installed for development purposes.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What installation process have you followed?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1599.sharepoint-foundation-2010-step-by-step-installation-guide.aspx

Comment: I am running the SharePointFoundation.exe and it says that this tool does not support the current operating system

Comment: What edition of windows 7 are you using?

Comment: Done after a lot on internet searching and hotfixes!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all OS should be 64 Bit.
Then you need to change config.xml file that you can find inside folder \files\Setup\config.xml. 
In this config.xml file you need to set

Answer (score 0):

I thisnk the smartest way in to created virtual environment on your PC.
http://dynamics.co.il